# How to make bottom corners of header rounded in Ionic

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic4

Im trying to implement such a header below.

[rounded bottom corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa8sE.png)

Here is my solution,

```css
ion-content {
    --background: #817afb; 
}

div.main {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ion-content fullscreen>
  <div class="main">
  ....
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

It is not working well when I try to use ion-refresher and ion-infinite-scroll. Anyone who has a solution suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-content {
    --background: #817afb; 
}

.main {

    enter code here
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px !important;
    
}
```